# Contract lookup with filter not working properly

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

On a Custom object (Timesheet), I have Account and Contract lookup fields.
The Contract lookup has a filter on it Timesheet.Account = Contract.Account.  Basically, I only want to see the Contracts of the Account that I have selected.

Unfortunately, the Contract lookup is not behaving as expected. When I type a search letter, it doesn't give me all the Contracts. For e.g. if I search with C*, it doesn't show all the contract names starting with C and having that account name.

What could be wrong? Below is field properties image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change condition to

> Contract.Account = Timesheet.Account

Comment: It didn't work. I just added the image in my original question